# Unable to browse hosted site on server

Tags: website, iis-7

I have hosted a website on a server which is working fine when I browse from a client machine. However when I browse the same site from the server I get: "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage."

The Internet is obviously working on the server. Whenever I ping the website from a Command Prompt I get replies, but when I browse it on server through a browser I always get the above message as if it is not able to reach the website.

Any guesses what the problem could be? I've checked the `hosts` file to see if there is anything strange in there but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to browse the website through it's non-FQDN name (UNC) from the server?

For example, "http://servername/site.aspx" instead of "http://www.mydomain.com/site.aspx".

If you can, this may mean you have DNS issues on the machine hosting IIS.